# Parent of <textarea> is taller than <textarea> when the document has <!DOCTYPE html> in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Try pasting this HTML into a file and opening it in Chrome:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The parent is a bit bigger than the textarea:

[image: size of textarea's parent]

This is only the case on Chrome (not Firefox).

I noticed that if I removed the doctype, it behaves normally - the parent is the correct size. My first thought is that it's just different default useragent styles. Here's a diff between the the user agent styles with and without the doctype:

[image: useragent styles with and without doctype]

So I tried matching the `padding` and the `box-sizing` like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <textarea style="box-sizing: border-box; padding: 2px 0px 0px 2px;"></textarea>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the problem doesn't go away. Any idea what's causing this?

(Sorry for the over-sized images - I'm not aware of any markdown tricks to make them a more reasonable size.)

Comment: Setting the vertical-align property on the textarea to middle or top appears to fix the issue, common with inline elements. The gap is reserved space for descender text elements.

Comment: Firefox does two things differently to Chromium here. It places the baseline of a textarea based on the font and line properties of its content, and it defaults the vertical alignment of textareas to text-bottom. Notably, in spite of [section 14.5.16 of the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#the-textarea-element-2) saying that a textarea should be rendered as an 'inline-block' box, neither treats its vertical alignment like one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a [chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=89530#c11).

The best workaround is to set it to block type box.

```
textarea {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I thought there must something fishy going on here - especially since it was only happening in Chrome. Thanks for hunting down the bug report!